# What is the name of the instrument used in this song?

Tags: strings

Does anyone know the name of this instrument used in this video at about 44 seconds into it?

It almost sounds like a woodwind and string instrument combined together and distorted a little

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything really because of the amount of effects seemingly involved in its timbre. It is very likely a synthesizer, but that sound could be created by a variety of instruments with various reverb effects, echo, filters, and so on. To my ear it could just as easily be a trumpet or a steel drum - the timbre is simply to vague to tell exactly what it could be. Note that this is also an orchestration effect, and that by giving specific timbres to specific instruments we can effect mood quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like a flute to me, although what it really sounds like is a flute sample on a synthesizer.

Also, I'd say that rather than all of the notes in the passage being directly sampled, most of them are the same sample with the frequency altered. That's why the two quick repeated notes a 4th lower sound a bit thin. There's also a whole lot of reverb on the notes, which is what gives it that distorted sound.